# Getting the value of time from a LocalDateTime class wont compile

Tags: java

I am trying to get the date and time value from a Date method in the `java.time.LocalDateTime`class. I have stored that value in a variable and I want to use it to set the parameter for an SQL query, but I am unable to extract the value. The code won't compile. I tried this:

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
query.setParameter("test", Date.valueOf(dt)); //error thrown here. I want to extract the current date and time ( hours, minutes, seconds) value stored in the dt variable
```

Comment: Which time value are you talking about? The hours, minutes, seconds and so (represents the time of day part only) on or the moment in time represented in milliseconds (represents date and time)?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Why not include the compiler error given to you? (and note: the compiler doesnt "throw" errors, terminology really matters).

Comment: If you just want  to make date of localDateTime than you can simply do it like this. Date date = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Date.valueOf(LocalDateTime)`, there is only [`Date.valueOf(LocalDate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDate)).

You need to use `LocalDate` directly or you can convert the `LocalDateTime` to `LocalDate` by calling [`toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toLocalDate()) on it.

Notice that `java.sql.Date` is actually not used for representing time-components like hours, minutes, seconds and so on. If you want both (date and time), then use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), which even has the method that you want: [`Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDateTime-).

---

Just a side note: The class for time-only is [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html).

Comment: Will `Date.valueOf(LocalDate);` return date and time or just date? I tried `toLocalDate` on it but still got an error. Could you please write code block out by updating the answer?

Comment: @Theman If you want date and time, then you are essentially using the wrong class. I've just updated the answer, which now mentions the class you need.

Comment: This works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a plain `java.time` solution without any relation to the outdated API around `java.util.Date`. `Date.valueOf(LocalDate)` just exists to make legacy code compatible with the modern datetime API (that is `java.time`).

Since you haven't clarified which *time* your question is about, I can just show different possibilities.

Please note that `LocalDateTime` is not suitable for catching timestamps because it does not contain information about your time zone or an offset, but you can add one if necessary:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get "now" without any time zone or offset information
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    // extract the date part
    LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate();
    // extract the time-of-day part
    LocalTime timeOfNow = now.toLocalTime();
    // then print the single parts (date and time of day)
    System.out.println("Today is " + today + " and now is " + timeOfNow + " that day");
    // print the full timestamp
    System.out.println("Full date and time are now " + now);
    // or print the epoch milliseconds (A ZONE OR AN OFFSET IS NEEDED THEN)
    System.out.println("Moment in time of now is "
                    + now.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli() + " in UTC");
}
```

The output of this is (see the output for execution time ;-) )

```
Today is 2020-08-13 and now is 15:04:46.728 that day
Full date and time are now 2020-08-13T15:04:46.728
Moment in time of now is 1597331086728 in UTC
```